# Need help translating a sentence

Tags: translation

The context is a coach's comment after losing a soccer game. (Full article here - http://www.giravanz.jp/game/report/2015/match39.html)

> 苦しい時間帯に何とか凌ぎながらゼロ失点でいくと勝ちゲームの流れを作れるのですが、ただ今日のゲームで言うと、あそこで耐えきれない、失点してしまうというのがまだまだ自分たちでゲームを作れないというゲームだったのではないかなと思います。

My translation:
We can tide over hard times, not concede and win games, but for today's game I think we couldn't hold them out and couldn't play how we wanted.

I'm pretty sure I understand the meaning, but I'm struggling to get it sounding natural in English. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing the essence of the statement, which is as long as they don't give up a point [even through the hard times as you stated] it can become a win.  But in [their] minds, once a points is given up it won't become a win.   (Seems weird he doesn't say 勝ちゲームの流れを作れない) but I think it's implied what he means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first half of the translation will be more clear if you phrase it as an if–then statement:

> 苦しい時間帯に 何とか凌ぎながらゼロ失点でいくと 勝ちゲームの流れを作れる
>   *If we can somehow manage to get through the difficult times of a game without losing points, we can set up the flow of a winning game*

The second half of your translation is fine. Since they couldn't hold them out, it was a game that showed they still were incapable of taking charge of a game.

(If it makes you feel any better, that Japanese sentence is rambling and poorly edited. It's a run-on, and doesn't even sound natural in Japanese. To make it sound natural in English, you might want to break it up into two sentences.)